# Regex needed for matching special characters at start of string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I require a modification to my existing regex to support special characters at the starting of a string value .

I currently have this expression :

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+.]{7,63}$/
```

This accepts any string between 8-64 chars , which has atleast 1 number , alphabet and a special symbol from the following : !@#$%^&*()_+.

How do I get it to recognize special characters at the start of an input value ?

Strings to be matched :

```
.abc@1234
*abc@1234
abc@1234.
a@b.c1234
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, this is really easy. Remove `[A-Za-z\d]` and replace `{7,63}` with `{8,64}`. [`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+.]{8,64}$`](https://regex101.com/r/mG8aD2/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This does not match the following :

*abc@1234
abc@1234.
a@b.c1234

Comment: [It does match them](https://regex101.com/r/mG8aD2/2).

Comment: You are also missing a `.` in the symbols positive lookahead

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just saw the difference in the regex I was trying and your solution .

You can provide this as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it as correct.

A side question .. How can I make sure that the special symbols never occur in consecutive positions ?
Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `[A-Za-z\d]` and replace `{7,63}` with `{8,64}`.

Use

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+.]{8,64}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG8aD2/2)

Perhaps, you also want to add the `.` back to the lookahead, so that it was also required:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+.])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+.]{8,64}$
                                         ^
```

To make sure the special symbols do not occur in immediate succession, add a `(?!.*[!@#$%^&*()_+.]{2})` *negative lookahead*:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+.])(?!.*[!@#$%^&*()_+.]{2})[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+.]{8,64}$
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG8aD2/3)

Note that a lot of people here would scream about mainainability issue of using such a long regex. You can either split the conditions into separate pieces of code, or use a multiline regex with comments:

```
var rx = RegExp("^" + // Start of string
               "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" + // Require a letter
               "(?=.*\\d)" + // Require a digit
               "(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])" + // Require a special symbol
               "(?!.*[!@#$%^&*()_+.]{2})" + // Disallow consecutive special symbols
               "[A-Za-z\\d!@#$%^&*()_+.]{8,64}" + // 8 to 64 symbols from the set
               "$");
```

```js
var re = RegExp("^" + // Start of string
               "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" + // Require a letter
               "(?=.*\\d)" + // Require a digit
               "(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])" + // Require a special symbol
               "(?!.*[!@#$%^&*()_+.]{2})" + // Disallow consecutive special symbols
               "[A-Za-z\\d!@#$%^&*()_+.]{8,64}" + // 8 to 64 symbols from the set
               "$", "gm");

var str = '.abc@1234\n*abc@1234\nabc@1234.\na@b.c1234\n*abc@1234\nabc@1234.\na@b.c1234\na@b.#c123\na@__c1234';
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  document.body.innerHTML += m[0] + "<br/>";
}
```