# regex to start with a capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have this regEx to match the following patterns:

```
/(((fall|spring|summer)\s\d{4});|(waived)|(sub\s[a-zA-Z]\d{3}))/ig
```

Should match:

```
fall 2000;
spring 2019; waived
summer 1982; sub T676
```

Should not match *ANY* string that does not start with the first capturing group `((fall|spring|summer)\s\d{4})` such as:

```
waived Fall 2014;
sub Fall 2011; waived
```

To make sure that each matching pattern starts with this group `((fall|spring|summer)\s\d{4})`
I tried appending `^` in front of the first group like this,  `/(^((fall|spring|summer)\s\d{4});|(waived)|(sub\s[a-zA-Z]\d{3}))/ig`, but the results were inconsistent.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2MWlR/5)

Comment: "*the results were inconsistent*" is not a problem description. See [mcve].

Comment: demo linked......

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but *also include the code in your question itself*.

Comment: `\s{1}` is functionally identical to `\s`, but some people prefer to be more visually explicit. I'm not fond of it, but it emphasizes _exactly one_ to the reader, so it does *something*. It's arguable whether it's a good thing, but I wouldn't knock someone for it.

Comment: Any particular reason you include the `^` inside the parens?

Comment: To make sure matching pattern starts with `((fall|spring|summer)\s\d{4})`

Comment: This pattern doesn't really make sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is not quite clear, try https://regex101.com/r/DOvMpw/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex needed for matching special characters at start of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901278/regex-needed-for-matching-special-characters-at-start-of-string)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That solved it. Please give a proper answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(fall|spring|summer)\s\d{4};(?:.*(waived|sub\s[a-zA-Z]\d{3}))?/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DOvMpw/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(fall|spring|summer)` - one of the three alternatives
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `(?:.*(waived|sub\s[a-zA-Z]\d{3}))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (if the values you need are closer to the start of string, replace with a lazy `.*?` counterpart)
  - `(` - start of a grouping construct

    - `waived` - a `waived` substring
    - `|` - or
    - `sub` - a `sub` substring
    - `\s` - a substring
    - `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
    - `\d{3}` - three digits
  - `)` - end of the grouping construct.